# How to load seperate .mat files using a drop down component in App Designer?

Tags: matlab, file, load, matlab-app-designer

I have separate .mat files, trials in a study, which consits of the same variables but the value change between files.

I want to use a drop-down component in MATLAB app designer to select a file, load its variables and display various plots.

Any ideas how I could do this?
Thank you in advance.

I had been loading a single file as a property like this:
var = load('Trial1.mat')
This code worked.

So then I tried to use this layout to load the files using the drop down menu but it didn't work..

```
 function SelectFileDropDownValueChanged(app, event)
            value = app.SelectFileDropDown.Value;
            if strcmp(value,'Trial 1')
                var = load('Trial1.mat');
            elseif strcmp(value,'Trial 2')
                var = load('Trial2.mat');
            elseif strcmp(value,'Trial 3')
                var = load('Trial3.mat');
            elseif strcmp(value,'Trial 4')
                var = load('Trial4.mat');
            elseif strcmp(value,'Trial5')
                var = load('Trial5.mat');
            end
```

Any ideas how I could do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

Add a new property named `var` to the `App` class.

You can add a private (or public) property in the EDITOR tab of the Designer:
[image]

Change the property name to `var` (matching your code sample).

Properties code block:

```
properties (Access = private)
    var % Description: store loaded variables
end
```

Now `var` is a class member.
The App Designer is based on Object-Oriented MATLAB Programming.
Accessing `var` is possible only withing the code of the `App` class (because it's a private member).
Accessing `var` property is as follows: `app.var` (`app` is a reference to class' object).
Note that `app` is the first parameter of class methods (as in `SelectFileDropDownValueChanged` method).

Modified `SelectFileDropDownValueChanged` code:

```
% Value changed function: SelectFileDropDown
function SelectFileDropDownValueChanged(app, event)
    value = app.SelectFileDropDown.Value;

    if strcmp(value,'Trial 1')
        app.var = load('Trial1.mat');
    elseif strcmp(value,'Trial 2')
        app.var = load('Trial2.mat');
    elseif strcmp(value,'Trial 3')
        app.var = load('Trial3.mat');
    elseif strcmp(value,'Trial 4')
        app.var = load('Trial4.mat');
    elseif strcmp(value,'Trial5')
        app.var = load('Trial5.mat');
    end           
end
```